# How do I deal with outdated/unmaintained dependencies that I could maintain locally on my own?

Tags: composer-php, dependency-management

I have a Laravel 5.3 project which I am upgrading to Laravel 5.4 and due to some changes in Laravel there are some dependencies that need updating. Every dependency except one had an updated I could safely switch to.

Checking github I found others with the same issue and an easy solution on how to fix the problem. However, due to unknown reasons the developer of the dependency has stated that they will no longer support it and would consider it deprecated. There are pull requests to fix the issue but no one can accept these requests.

What I can do is navigate to my vendor folder and make the changes myself but I know this isn't the right way to do things as the changes will get overwritten eventually and we are back to square one.

**How do I deal with the problem of outdated/unmaintained dependencies with problems I could fix on my own or solve with the help of others who share their solutions?**

1) I could copy the files from vendor and try to just integrate the third party files into my project.

2) I could fork the repository and make the required changes and either add my forked version to packagist (doesn't feel right) or add my forked git as a repository in the composer.json file.

I am open to other ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add the way I have solved it for now. If someone has a better answer I would gladly accept it.

In my case the repository in question is a Github repository which I could fork. I can then clone the repository and make any needed changes. Let's say that the following is what I have in my composer.json file.

```
"require": {
    "someoneelse/project": "^1.0"
}
```

Inside my composer.json file I found the "someoneelse/project" for the dependency and changed the current version requirement "^1.0" to "dev-master". This will pull the latest commit from the master branch and put minimum-stability as dev.

I then added my repository to composer.json. You can do this like so

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/markustenghamn/project.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "someoneelse/project": "dev-master"
}
```

Running composer update will now fetch the latest version from my forked repository. If someone decides to start working on this project again I can always change it back. The dependency may require other dependencies in forked projects composer.json file, remember to update these if needed.